# Range Proof without trusted set-up

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

If verifiers are public blockchain nodes, which might leak information. Does this imply that range proofs such as Boudot's and Lipmma's (squaring based) approach could not be applied, unless a trusted set-up is used?

In this case, if we need a range proof without trusted set-up, what are the choices out there? Bullet range proof? any other altnernatives?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant links?

Comment: Bulletproof. There is a new paper called bulletproof+ on eprint. Dan Boneh wrote a sketch on how to use polynomial commitment to construct range proof, so I guess you can also use polynomial commitment that does not require trusted set up to do rangeproof

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the links for Boudot's and Lipmma's:
(1) Boudot's paper: https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070437-new.pdf (2) Lipmaa's: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-40061-5_26.pdf